# C# Code Optimization GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, foreach, linq-group

I have a couple of problems with my below code.

```
var groupedItems = inputFiles.GroupBy(q => q.Name.ToLower().Split('_').ElementAt(2));
        string currentNo = ////value retreived from someMethod;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNo))
        {
            if (groupedItems.Count() > 1)
            {
                foreach (var group in groupedItems)
                {
                    foreach (var groupedItem in group)
                    {
                        ErrorFile(groupedItem);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (groupedItems.Count() == 1)
            {
                ProcessFile();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var group in groupedItems.Where(x => x.Key != currentNo))
            {
                foreach (var groupedItem in group)
                {
                    ErrorFile(groupedItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

- There is repetitive code with nested foreach loops. I am looking at possibility of optimization
- How do I handle when Split and ElementAt(2) return errors. I still need to call ErrorFile() method even if I am unable to Split by _.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand what your code is really doing without more context, but this should be about right:

```
static void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<File> inputFiles)
{
    var groupedItems = inputFiles.GroupBy
        (f => splitAndFindElement(f.Name, '_', 2, string.Empty));

    string currentNo = //whatever;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNo))
    {
        if (groupedItems.Count() > 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in groupedItems.SelectMany(g => g))
            {
                ErrorFile(item);
            }
        }
        else if (groupedItems.Count() == 1)
        {
            ProcessFile();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in groupedItems.Where(g => g.Key != currentNo).SelectMany(g => g))
        {
            ErrorFile(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And the helper method:

```
static string splitAndFindElement(string input, char splitter, int index, string resultOnFail)
{
    var succesful = false;
    string[] words = null;

    if (input != null)
    {
        words = input.Split(splitter);
        succesful = words.Length > index;
    }

    return succesful ? words[index] : resultOnFail;
}
```

The trick here is to group files with key `""` if they can't be split. This will ensure that they will be processed with `ErrorFile` either becuase there is more than one grouping or because the key does not equal `currentNo`. I'm assuming here that `Name` can't end in `"_"`.

Also, `SelectMany` is used to flatten enumerables of enumerables and avoid nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

We can optimize repeated loops as following, and to handle error use try catch

```
var groupedItems;
try
{
    groupedItems= inputFiles.GroupBy(q => q.Name.ToLower().Split('_').ElementAt(2));

    string currentNo = ////value retreived from someMethod;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNo) && groupedItems.Count() == 1)
    {
        ProcessFile();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var group in groupedItems.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentNo) || x.Key != currentNo))
        {
            foreach (var groupedItem in group)
            {
                ErrorFile(groupedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    ErrorFile(groupedItem);
}
```